# Adding comments with pdfcomment without affecting the document

Tags: pdfcomment

If you use a pdf-viewer to add comments to a pdf document, you do not modify the typesetting - of course.

I would like to have the same behaviour using a command of the `pdfcomment` package (or other package).

My problem is, that `pdfcomment` in some cases adds vertical space in the text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\begin{document}
    \section{Section 1 Title}
    \pdfmargincomment{This leads to additional  vertical space :-(}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item additional vertical space above :-(
    \end{itemize}

        \section{Section 2 Title}

        \begin{itemize}
            \item normal vertical space above :-)
        \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE]

Answer (score 3):

Macro `\pdfmargincomment` takes up no space when it is placed beside something, but `itemize` does not like to be beside anything.  In fact it adds `\par` if it doesn't start in vertical mode.

If you put the `itemize` inside a `minipage`, then one can put the `\pdfmargincomment` beside the `minipage`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\begin{document}
    \section{Section 1 Title}
    \pdfmargincomment{This leads to additional  vertical space :-(}%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{\textwidth}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item additional vertical space above :-(
    \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}

        \section{Section 2 Title}

        \begin{itemize}
            \item normal vertical space above :-)
        \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: OK, you say:  there is no simple solution that fits to all cases.  Thank you.

Comment: ``\marginpar{\pdfcomment{Hello}}`` seems to be more robust than ``\pdfmargincomment{Hello}`` if you place it between ``\section{test1}`` and ``\subsection{test2}`` e.g.

Comment: i believe \pdfmargincomment uses a \tikzmark while \marginpar doesn't.  OTOH, there are places you cannot use \marginpar either.